# Deep autoencoder: validation loss doesn't change

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, loss-function, autoencoder

I'm trying to understand autoencoders and reproduced some code from Keras [documentation](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html):

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)


autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=64,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

And when I start fitting the model I see the next validation loss.

```
Epoch 1/100
938/938 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0270 - val_loss: 0.0040
Epoch 2/100
938/938 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0039 - val_loss: 0.0040
Epoch 3/100
938/938 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0039 - val_loss: 0.0040
...
Epoch 100/100
938/938 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0035 - val_loss: 0.0036
```

However, there is another val_loss value in the documentation:

> After 100 epochs, it reaches a train and validation loss of ~0.08

Is this overfitting? Why it happens so fast? Why there is another value in the documentation? I tried different learning_rate: 0.01, 0.0001, and nothing helped.
I also tried to use `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, monitor='val_loss')` callback but it didn't stop and I don't understand why.